# Monotouch.Dialog: After selection in a RadioElement table, how to update a dependent table?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am developing a Unit Converter using Monotouch.Dialog, and I have a main window that looks like this:

[image: Unit converter main window]

When I tap the Quantity element, select a new Quantity and return to the main window, I want to update the Unit elements with a table of units associated with the selected quantity.

My initial thought was to make an update of the units in an event handler that would be invoked after completed quantity selection. However, I have not been able to find an event in the MT.D API that is fired when I return from the quantity selection. Is there such an event that I could act upon, or is there another way I can do the unit updating?

Schematically, my `AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching` method looks like this right now:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
  _window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

  _quantityGroup = new RadioGroup("Qty", 0);
  _fromUnitGroup = new RadioGroup("FromU", 0);
  _toUnitGroup = new RadioGroup("ToU", 0);

  var quantityElem = new RootElement("Quantity", _quantityGroup) { 
      new Section() { new RadioElement("AbsorbedDose", "Qty") as Element, ... }};

  var fromUnitElem = new RootElement("Unit", _fromUnitGroup) { new Section() };
  var toUnitElem = new RootElement("Unit", _toUnitGroup) { new Section() }

  _rootElement = new RootElement ("Unit Converter")
  {
    new Section() { quantityElem }, 
    new Section("From") { new EntryElement(...), fromUnitElem },
    new Section("To") { new EntryElement(...), toUnitElem }
  };

  _rootVC = new DialogViewController(_rootElement);
  _nav = new UINavigationController(_rootVC);

  _window.RootViewController = _nav;
  _window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

  return true;
}
```

Comment: see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302306/monotouch-dialog-responding-to-a-radiogroup-choice.  I have a more complete example somewhere if you need it.

Comment: Great, many thanks for your help, Jason! I searched for an SO answer before posting my question, but I did not see that one. As also pointed out in the comments in that answer, this would be a great addition to MT.D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Jason in a comment above this problem had been addressed previously on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302306/monotouch-dialog-responding-to-a-radiogroup-choice).

The solution is to extend the `RadioElement` class, where the inheriting class contains an `OnSelected` event and the `RadioElement.Selected` method is overridden with a method that invokes the `OnSelected` event handler(s).

Comment: Does anyone else think that there should be a better way do do this? I don't know one right now... but, I'm continuing my search